# AS3 и ООП- во что обернуть несколько действий?

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-3

В main.as есть кнопки, слушатель и обработчик onClick. Вот в обработчике (построенный через switch) на каждую из кнопок задуманы разные блоки с инструкциями. Как правильнее с точки зрения ООП в ActionScript эти блоки организовать? Поместить в функции в теле main? Поместить в функии в отдельный класс? Написать в самом обработчике?

Answer (score 2):

По моему, это не совсем по ООП вопрос. Тут скорее вопрос читабельности и удобства. Я редко видел, чтоб для нескольких кнопок использовался один обработчик и в нем свичем проверялось какая именно кнопка нажата, чаще всего, каждой кнопке соответствует свой слушатель события `onButtonStartClick()`, `onButtonStopClick()` к примеру. Хотя, в некоторых случаях может быть целесообразно использовать и switch. Для более полного ответа нужна более полная информация по задаче, что за кнопки, что происходит при нажатии и т.п.

Comment: Благодарю Иван, что уделили моему вопросу время. Собственно пишу простенькую игру, 5 кнопок в меню: "Играть", "Помощь", "Об игре", "Опции", "Выход". Все действия довольно простые (тот же "Выход" уместился одной командой в блоке case. С пунктами "Помощь" и "Об игре" уже стало сложнее, вынес рисование текстов в отдельную функцию (передаю ей имя кнопки, по If рисую тот или иной текст). А вот с "Играть" понял что всю логику игры в case засунуть как то совсем неправильно.

Comment: Правда мне уже подсказали такой вариант: все оформить в отдельные классы на основе Sprite и просто играть видимостью того или иного спрайта. Это верно? Просто я с процедурного программирования (Pascal + Delphi) и пока не совсем понимаю как тут правильно строить структуру программы.

Comment: Для каждой кнопки лучше сделать свой слушатель события, как я и писал. Почитай про MVC и другие архитектурные шаблоны, это может значительно упростить работу с архитектурой приложения.

Comment: [Что делать когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)